# SQL-Filter for driver-tours

Tags: mysql

I don't need the exact SQL-statement I just need some crowd intel to do the math. 
I want to write a tool for truck-drivers to bid on tours.
They deliver cargo on certain routes in a late and a early shift.

There are defined tours e.g. DAY1 Start in Hamburg, Germany, via Munich, Germany, to Italy. Day 2....

The drivers also have the possibility to pick from a list of wildcard requests
1) Lateshift
2) Earlyshift
3) A tour that includes one certain stop (e.g. 1 night in Paris)

If two drivers bid on the same tour the driver that's with the company for the longest time should get it.

The math for the tours is easy: If a driver looks at a tour, I look for all requests on that tour, sort the requests by date-of-entry of the other employee and if he's with us longer that the one that wants to request the tour than the tour will be red otherwise greeen.

Now my problem are the wildcard-requests. They are just collected by the system and aren't paired to a certain tour until the roster is acutally created.
The problem: The wildcard-requests have the same priority as the regular tour-requests.

Example: Employee 1 (entry 2010) requests 1 night in Paris between the 1st and the 5th of June. 
There is only one tour with a night in paris in that time-range which is requested by Employee 2 (entry 2011) who wouldn't get it, because the wildcard-request of EM1 overrules him.

How would I accomplish a valid green/red display for the tours with the damn wildcard-requests in mind?
The system would work like this: If I look at a tour the system must look at all wildcard-requests by older employees and check if there are alternatives to left to fullfil the request, right?

Thanks for any ideas!!